# MySQL INSERT SELECT FROM multiple tables if record doesn't already exist

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that essentially looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO lessons_skills_xref (lessons_id, skills_id)
SELECT id FROM lessons, (SELECT id FROM skills WHERE title = "title 1")
/* PSEUDO CODE - Where the ids for both lesson and skill don't already exist */
```

Not sure how to accomplish the last part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `lessons_skills_xref` has a unique key on (lessons_id,skills_id), an easy way would be to just use `INSERT IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO lessons_skills_xref (lessons_id, skills_id)
SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM skills WHERE title = "title 1") FROM lessons
```

The `INSERT IGNORE` syntax will insert the record if it doesn't already exist, or ignore it if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO lessons_skills_xref (lessons_id, skills_id)

SELECT lessons.id, skills.id FROM lessons
inner join skills on <join criteria here>

where not exists (select 1 from lessons_skill_xref x where
                  x.lessons_id = lessons.id and x.skills_id = skills.id)

and skills.title = "title 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to generate a Cartesian join between every lesson.id and the skills.id for the "title 1" skill?  I'm not sure your SELECT clause will work.  This may:

```
    INSERT INTO lessons_skills_xref (lessons_id, skills_id)
    (SELECT l.id, s.id FROM lessons l, skills s 
        WHERE s.title = "title 1"
        AND NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM lessons_skills_xref 
                WHERE lessons_id=l.id 
                AND skills_id=s.id)
    );
```

Note that this is untested.